# My mat-tab-group index is always goes at the end

Tags: angular

I am implementing the option for the tab to remember the last option where the user left off, I am saving the value in localStorage and it works correctly when viewed from the console, however, if the index is for example "2", it always goes to the end no matter what.
Here is my code

```
<mat-tab-group #tabs animationDuration="0ms" disableRipple  [selectedIndex]="indexSelected"
      (selectedTabChange)="onTabChanged($event)">
  <mat-tab> ... </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab> ... </mat-tab>
   <mat-tab> ... </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

My ts:

```
  public onTabChanged(tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent): void {
    this.indexSelected = tabChangeEvent.index;
    this.localStorage.saveItem('lastTabUser', this.indexSelected);
    this.change.markForCheck();
  }
```

And

```
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.indexSelected = this.localStorage.getSavedItem('lastTabUser') || 0;
    this.change.detectChanges();
  }
```

I have a localStorage service (for other uses too)

```
  public saveItem(name: string, value: any): void{
    localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(value));
  }

  public getSavedItem(name: string): any{
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name));
  }
```

I use ChangeDetectorRef to detect changes.
and i really don't understand this behavior, being that I am correctly saving the value of the last tab in the localstorage. Is it something in the AfterContent or AfterView?

Comment: localStorage only allows storing strings, so your `indexSelected` gets stringified - i.e. it's not `2`, it's "2". When fetching the data from localStorage, use parseInt() to cast the value to number. Not sure if that will help, but that would be my first hunch.

Comment: @TotallyNewb you are right, but now I am passing the indexSelected as a number and it still goes to the end, even though in the console it shows the correct index, so I think it is something in the afterContent but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tddtq9) reproduction for you, which seems to be working as expected. The only difference is parsing `indexSelected` using `parseInt()`, removal of change detection since it's not needed and omitting your service and accessing localStorage directly.

So I assume your issue is linked either to:

- Your LocalStorageService
- Some other logic within the component that you have not posted

If you need further help, reproduce your issue where it's NOT working on stackblitz.

Comment: thanks a lot for stackblitz, clarified how to deal with strings and numbers from localStorage. With your answer, it work, but also i found the problem on my side: ngx-permissions. I use this library in a mat-tab to show or not content depending on the permissions, removing this permission works perfectly.
I will look for a way to implement these permissions along with the desired behavior in the tab. Again, thank you and I mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this

```
public onTabChanged(tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent): void {
    this.indexSelected = tabChangeEvent.index;
    localStorage.setItem('lastTabUser', this.indexSelected);
    this.change.markForCheck();
}

ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.indexSelected = localStorage.getItem('lastTabUser') || 0;
    this.change.detectChanges();
}
```